# Model within a model is returned as null

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a model property for my model. The property is set inside the controller upon creation, but I cannot get the value upon submission

```cs
public class Item
{
   public Vendor mVendor { get; set; }
}
```

We have this class Item that has a vendor. The vendor is its own model, and the item creation interface is accessed from the vendor controller.

```cs
public ActionResult Create(int? vendorID)
{
   if (vendorID != null)
   {
      Item item = new Item { mVendor = db.Vendors.Find(vendorID) };
      return View(item);
   }
}
```

And now here's the submission code

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Create(Item item)
{
   if (ModelState.IsValid)
   {
      db.Items.Add(item);
      db.SaveChanges();
      return RedirectToAction("Index");
   }
}
```

When it gets to the submission code, it says that the vendor is null. I've tried putting a HiddenFor in the view, but that doesn't seem to fix anything. Does anyone have any suggestions?

**EDIT:**
Code for the view:

```cs
@model Models.Item

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create";
}

<h2>Item Sheet</h2>
<p><font color="red">@ViewBag.Error</font></p>

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

<div class="form-horizontal">
    <h4>Item Data (@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Vendor.name))</h4>
    <hr />
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

    <div class="form-group">
        <p>Item Number:</p>
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.PartNo, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @id = "PartNumber" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.PartNo, "", new { @class = "text-danger", @Value = ""})
        </div>
    </div>

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

Comment: What does your view contain?

Comment: It's the standard Create() view that Visual Studio generates.

((I pressed enter and submitted this comment too early, going to paste the code shortly))

Comment: Your form lacks `Vendor` fields. So nothing will be submitted.

Comment: So, if I want the Vendor value to be set in the controller, how would I allow for vendor submission without letting the user change this value?

Comment: You could make it a hidden or read-only field. But ultimately, you'll need server-side validation to prevent manipulated requests hitting your service.

Comment: I included an HTML.HiddenFor but it still has the same runtime error.

Comment: Please show us the code for that attempt. It would be `@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.mVendor.Id)`

Comment: That's exactly what it was. I tried something out just now. I put an editor in there for the vendor anyway. When I load up the form, it shows the Vendor name, ID, etc for the Item I'm making.But, it still has the same error when I click submit. The vendor is null...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if your using entity framework and a your data tables have relations then you can use ***eager loading*** to load vendor data for each item in your item list.look at the below Data Model as an Example

```
public class Vendor_Details
{
    public Vendor_Details()
    {
        Items = new HashSet<Items_List>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Vendor_Name { get; set; }
    public string Vendor_Code { get; set; }
    public string Vendor_Email { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Items_List> Items { get; set; }

}

public class Items_List
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Item_Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public decimal Item_Price { get; set; }
    public int Vendor_Id { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Vendor_Id")]
    public Vendor_Details Vendor { get; set; }
}
```

And Below is the Example Ef Query to Load Data

```
var itemList = databaseContext.Items_List.Include("Vendor").ToList();
```

this way You can Load both Vendors and their items at the same time and then be cached to improve the Application performance as well reducing database round trips.

Comment: This is a really useful pattern. I'm not used to web/desktop application architecture considering most of my programming experience comes from game dev. Thank you so much for the pointers!

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the model like `@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.mVendor.Id)` since you are using a model within the model.

Also I don't recommend using model within a model unless you required other data within your view.

Comment: What's your recommended alternative? I'd like the Vendors to have a list of items, and for the items to have a pointer to which vendor they belong to.

Comment: please refer to my below detailed comment